# How to I set Queue Name dynamically in "Set Working Queue" in Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I want to set the Queue in "`Set working queue`" without specifying Queue name explicitly. I would like to set the queue name dynamically the same as the value in a user-defined attribute. Because in the future, if more queues are added, I want to avoid modifying the contact flow. I tried to set this by using the "`Set dynamically`" option but it didn't work. Can someone help with this, please?

Answer (score 2):

When you set the working queue dynamically you need to set it either as the queue's full ARN or just the id (the guid at the end of the ARN). You can find the ARN by going to the queue in Connect and clicking `Show additional queue information`

If you wanted to use the queue name, you'd need to setup a lambda that does a lookup via the Connect API to get the ARN of the queue based on the name, then call that first and use the results from that in the set working queue block.

Comment: 1. How can I set queue dynamically by setting queue's Full ARN? because if we are specifying each queue's ARN, then it becomes static right?

Comment: 2. Suppose from the lambda function I return queue ARN. How can I set it in set working queue block? Is it by using "External" option?

Comment: Your lambda will return some json. Set the result from the lambda to be 
`{"id": "07d0187d-2160-495e-af86-c2eac6afa4c8"}` for example. Then in the Set working queue block, set the set the Namespace to `External` and the Key to `id`